# Use generic types in TypeGuard function with mypy

Tags: python, mypy

I have a function that checks if a list contains `None` and I want to use it to narrow the type of the input variable:

```
from typing import List, Optional, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import TypeGuard

_ListElementsType = TypeVar("_ListElementsType")


def sequence_not_contains_none(maybe_optional_list: List[Optional[_ListElementsType]]) -> TypeGuard[List[_ListElementsType]]:
    return not (None in maybe_optional_list)
```

When using this function with input `List[Optional[int]]`:

```
integer_list: List[Optional[int]] = [10, 11, 12]
reveal_type(integer_list)
if int_sequence_not_contains_none(integer_list):
    reveal_type(integer_list)
```

I get the wrong return type:

```
note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[Union[builtins.int, None]]"
note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[_ListElementsType`-1]"
```

where I would have expected that the second type is `List[int]`.

If I switch out the generic type with a fixed `int` it works. As far as I understand [PEP 647](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0647/#id5) the version using generics should also be supported. The mypy version used is `mypy 0.910` (`python 3.8.10`)

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been reported: [#11428](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11428)

The Pylance type hinting gets it right though. (Tested with: Pylance v2021.11.0 and Python 3.10.0)